Dynamically perform calculation down column in R
I have data that looks like this:
library(tidyverse)
df<-tibble(date = as.Date("2024-07-01"), starting_n = 100, growth_rate = 0.05)%>%
bind_rows(
tibble(date = seq.Date(as.Date("2024-08-01"), as.Date("2024-09-01"), by = "month"), growth_rate = 0.05))
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  date       starting_n growth_rate
  <date>          <dbl>       <dbl>
1 2024-07-01        100        0.05
2 2024-08-01         NA        0.05
3 2024-09-01         NA        0.05

I am trying to calculate starting_n based on the initial starting_n and growth_rate such that the growth rate is applied cumulatively down the column like this:
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  date       starting_n growth_rate starting_n_calc
  <date>          <dbl>       <dbl>           <dbl>
1 2024-07-01        100        0.05             NA 
2 2024-08-01         NA        0.05            105 
3 2024-09-01         NA        0.05            110.25

I have tried the following:
df%>%mutate(starting_n_calc=lag(first(starting_n)*growth_rate+first(starting_n)))
   date       starting_n growth_rate starting_n_calc
  <date>          <dbl>       <dbl>           <dbl>
1 2024-07-01        100        0.05              NA
2 2024-08-01         NA        0.05             105
3 2024-09-01         NA        0.05             105

As shown, it only produces the first calculation and fills down, rather than dynamically calculating down the column.
I have tried a few other combinations of lag, first, and cumsum but nothing seems to work. Please help! Thanks.

Is growth rate constant and just repeated on each row, or is it variable? Which rate goes with which line?

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60682659/efficiently-apply-a-growth-rate-to-an-initial-value-for-varying-growth-rates-ove

@MrFlick it is repeated

You could do it this way with cumprod and lag:
df |> mutate(starting_n_calc = lag((starting_n[1] * cumprod(growth_rate+1))))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   date       starting_n growth_rate starting_n_calc
#>   <date>          <dbl>       <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1 2024-07-01        100        0.05             NA 
#> 2 2024-08-01         NA        0.05            105 
#> 3 2024-09-01         NA        0.05            110.


This appears to get the job done. Thank you!
